# Angular: styles.css vs. styles.xxxx.css

Tags: angular, pipe, config

While developing looks the style link in DOM "normal".

On production a hex number is added and looks like this example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.2a837f84c87615489567.css">
```

Which parameter must be set (in "angular.json"?) do avoid adding the number?
What else must be done?

Comment: the numbers is a hash. Why do you want to remove them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify your generated bundles that should not have numbers, then you can easily configure that by modifying `angular.json` [options](https://angular.io/cli/build#options) `outputHashing` to `none`

**angular.json**

```
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        ....
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          ...,
          outputHashing: none,
         ...
      },
    },
 },
```

OR

pass `--output-hashing=none` parameter to command.

```
ng build --prod --output-hashing=none.
```

Comment: "@Pankaj Parkar": Works perfect! Thanks! I have marked your answer as solution!
I had just to change the value from "all" to (the default value!) "none". ;-)